# Show that $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx=0$ for all $g\in C([0,1])$ implies $f=0$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in L^1([0,1])$ be an absolutely integrable function. Show that if $f$ satisfies 
$$\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx=0$$
for all continuous function $g\in C([0,1])$, then $f=0$ a.e.

First consider the case that $f$ is bounded, let $M$ be a bound of $f$. Notice that $C([0,1])$ is dense in $L^{1}([0,1])$, thus we can find a sequence of continuous functions $g_n\in C([0,1])$ such that $\|g_n-f\|_{L^1}\to 0$. Then the claim easily follows from
$$\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^1 f(x)(f(x)-g_n(x))\,dx\leq M\|f-g_n\|_{L^1}.$$
I don't know how to show the case that $f$ is not bounded?

Comment: Instead of approximating $f$, try to approximate $sgn (f)$ (its sign) in a bounded way. If $f = r e^{i \theta}$ is complex-valued, try to approximate $e^{-i \theta}$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to approximate $1_E$. We shall show that 
$$\int_{[0,1]} f1_E\,dx=0$$
for every measurable subset $E$ of $[0,1]$.

$f$ is absolutely integrable,  thus uniformly integrable. That is  for every $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|\int_{[0,1]} f1_{E}\,dx|\leq \varepsilon$$
for every measurable set $E$ with $m(E)\leq \delta$.

Now suppose that $E$ is a measurable subset of $[0,1]$. By the regularity of Lebesgue measure, we can find an open set $U$ and a compact set $K$ with $K\subset E\subset U$ such that $m(U\setminus K)\leq \delta$, thus 
$$|\int_{[0,1]} f1_{U\setminus K}\,dx|\leq \varepsilon.$$
By Urysohn's lemma,  we can find a continuous function $g$ with $1_{K}\leq g\leq 1_{U}$. Then we have
$$|\int_{[0,1]} f1_E\,dx|=|\int_{[0,1]} f(1_E-g)\,dx|\leq |\int_{[0,1]} f1_{U\setminus K}\,dx|\leq \varepsilon.$$
Then claim then follows by sending $\varepsilon$ to zero. To finish the proof, we can use the following equality
$$\int_{[0,1]}|f|\,dx=\int_{[0,1]} f1_{f\geq 0}\,dx-\int_{[0,1]}f1_{f<0}\,dx=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The boundedness of $f$ is not necessary. The fact that $C[0,1])$ is dense in $L^1$ implies the existence of such a sequence $g_n$ independently of boundedness restrictions on $f.$

Now $f$ itself may not be square integrable, but for fixed constant $R>0$ the maximum of $f$ and $R$ is. Your argument proves that at least the latter function is 0 almost everywhere; the arbitrariness of $R$ then leads to the conclusion that $f$ itself is 0 almost everywhere.

Comment: If $f$ is not bounded, how to estimate $\int_0^1 f(x)(f(x)-g_n(x))\,dx$

Comment: OK I have added a paragraph to clarify this.

Comment: I guess that you mean the minimum of $f$ and $R$. $\int_0^1 fg=0$ does not implies $\int_0^1 \min(f,R)g=0$, I don't think the same argument works

Comment: I really mean the maximum, which is a bounded continuous function and therefore 0 a.e. by your argument.

Answer (score 1):

For any fixed $f\in\mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1])$ we can define a linear functional $\mathscr{l}_{f}:C([0,1]) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $$\mathscr{l}_{f}(g)= \int_{0}^{1}g(x)\, f(x) \, dx$$ It is easy to see that $\mathscr{l}_{f}$ is bounded, since indeed $$|\mathscr{l}_{f}(g)|\leq \int_{0}^{1}|g(x)| \, |f(x)| \, dx\leq \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|g(x)| \cdot ||f||_{\mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1])}$$ yielding $||\mathscr{l}_{f}||_{*}\leq ||f||_{\mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1])}$

Moreover we can find a sequence of continuous functions approximating $sgn(f)$, thus by using dominated convergence theorem we can actually prove that $$||\mathscr{l}_{f}||_{*}=||f||_{\mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1])}$$

Now the claim says that $\mathscr{l}_{f}(g)=0$ for all $g\in C([0,1])$, but this can only happen if $\mathscr{l}_{f}\equiv 0$ i.e if and only if $$||f||_{\mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1])}=||\mathscr{l}_{f}||_{*} =0$$ i.e iff $f\equiv 0$ almost-everywhere on $[0,1]$

Comment: We can find a sequence of continuous functions approximating $\text{sgn}(f)$, can you say this more clearly? in which norm? $L^\infty$ or $L^1$ norm? Since the space of continuous functions with sup-norm is complete,  we cannot approximate $\text{sgn}(f)$ by continuous functions unless it is continuous.

Comment: First you say $sgn(f)$ is in $\mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1])$, in which continuous functions are dense. So you pick $\left\{g_{n}\right\}_{n\geq1}\subset C([0,1])$ such that $||g_{n}-sgn(f)||_{\mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1])}\rightarrow 0$. Then we can extract a subsequence $\left\{g_{n_{j}}\right\}$ such that $g_{n_{j}}\rightarrow sgn(f)$ pointwise a.e.

Comment: Now we have a subsequence $g_{n_j}$ converges to $\text{sgn}(f)$ pointwise, but how to deduce that $\int fg_{n_j}$ converges to $\int f\text{sgn}(f)$? It seems that we need the sequence $fg_{n_j}$  to be dominated.

Comment: Well, maybe i should had required a bit more of our $g_{n}$'s. Namely that $||g_{n}||_{\infty} \leq 1$ for all $n\geq 1$. Do you agree that this can be done?

Comment: Do you mean that we replace  the sequence $g_{n_j}$ by its truncated sequence $g'_{n_j}=\max(\min(g_{n_j},1),-1)$?

Comment: Well, that works as long as we remain continuous.

Comment: The maximum and minimum of two continuous functions is always continuous, and the new sequence converges to the same limit, so we are done. But the proof is not very natural,  it there a better proof?